# expandable view display text in point form align

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

I want to create a FAQs page to my apps, which has a "Question" as title and "Answer" as result while question is clicked.
[I'm using this tutorial as references](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-expandable-news-feed-example-4b4544e1fe7e)

 However, in certain case i will need to perform the result in point form with proper align [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0om1.png)

 I'm thinking of using HTML format and using HTML view in android side, however, can JSON store the HTML code and result it in HTML view correctly once i read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive your goal by using 2 or 3 level Expandable list view.
Here I give you link . Follow it.

https://gist.github.com/st-f/2b2a838d3f0258c5c33f

Comment: Thanks! this is useful to me